# Form Data doesn't show correctly when I send it via Fetch with Node & Muller & Mongoose & GirdFS

Tags: node.js, reactjs

I'm trying to upload a new thumbnail with my new quiz, but I'm getting a type of error 500 with the message:

`xhr.js:210 POST http://localhost:1234/api/user/61c17715dca0ed0006d92ff9/quizzes/create-quiz 500 (Internal Server Error)`

I'm Using MERN stack and GridFS & Muller but I don't know what the error is:

Here is my api base:

```
const API_BASE_URL = "http://localhost:1234/api/user";

const { user_id, token } = authState.auth;

const client = axios.create({
  baseURL: API_BASE_URL,
  headers: {
    "Content-type": "application/json",
    Authorization: "Bearer " + token,
  },
});
```

Here is my API:

```
export const createQuiz = (data) => async (dispatch) => {
  let user = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("user"));

  const { title, questions, thumbnail, description, category, purchaseCoins, privacy, difficulty } =
    data;
  const newObj = {
    created_by: user.user_id,
    title,
    description,
    category,
    questions,
    filename: thumbnail,
    purchaseCoins,
    privacy,
    difficulty,
  };
  console.log("this is it:", newObj);
  
  try {
    const response = await api.createQuiz(newObj);
    const data = await response.data;
    window.location.href = "/dashboard/quizzes";
    console.log(data)
    dispatch({ type: CONST.ADD_QUIZ_SUCCEEDED, payload: data });
  } catch (error) {
    console.log(error)
    dispatch({ type: CONST.ADD_QUIZ_FAILED, payload: error });
  }
};
```

Here is my React code:

```
<input
  className={styles._form_input}
  type="file"
  id="l-quiz-name"
  name="image"
  placeholder="Quiz Name"
  onChange={(e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    let newData = { ...quiz };
    const formData = new FormData();
    let currentlyUploaded = e.target.files[0];
    formData.append(currentlyUploaded.name, currentlyUploaded);
    newData["thumbnail"] = formData;
    setQuiz(newData);
  }}
/>;
```

And here is my route at the back:

```
router.post(
  `${prefix}/create-quiz`,
  userAuth,
  upload.single("thumbnail"),
  async (req, res) => {
    try {
      const user = await User.findOne({ _id: req.params.userId });
      console.log(req.file.thumbnail)
      const newQuiz = new Quiz({
        purchaseCoins: req.body.purchaseCoins,
        privacy: req.body.privacy,
        created_by: req.params.userId,
        category: req.body.category,
        title: req.body.title,
        description: req.body.description,
        difficulty: req.body.difficulty,
        questions: req.body.questions,
        thumbnail: req.file.filename,
      });

      console.log(newQuiz);
      await newQuiz.save();
      user.quizzes.push(newQuiz._id);
      await user.save();

      return res.status(201).json({
        message: "Finally , a quiz created properly !",
        success: true,
      });
    } catch (error) {
      return res.status(500).json({
        message: "Can't save this quiz try again, check if it already exists",
        success: false,
      });
    }
  }
);
```

And this is the data on how the object is being sent to NodeJS:
[image: console log before is sent to database]

Comment: And what error do you get on the server then? If it returns status 500 you should see an error in terminal.

Comment: @Molda nope nothing this is weird

Comment: Sometimes thumbnail is undefined

Comment: So is the status 500 caused by this line `return res.status(500)...` in the catch block? If so add `console.log(error);` to see the error.

Comment: @Molda yes i did i got this: "Cannot read property 'thumbnail' of undefined"

Comment: I just noticed you used `file` instead of `files` try with **files** instead `req.files.thumbnail`

Comment: Doesn't work i thin itas the front end